# Is it possible to put a Windows 10 installation setup on the HDD from ubuntu and make it bootable

Tags: boot, windows, boot-partition

I would like to put a windows 10 setup on an extra partition and then start the windows installation process from it. For this I guess I would have to unpack the iso, place the content on some partition on the HDD and then boot the windows setup from there.

Is that possible? How would I configure the bootmanager and make the partition bootable?

Background:
Fairly old PC that I can't get to boot from a USB Drive, no CD-Drive in the house, but still with a working ubuntu installation(12.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with grub:

1. Create extra partition
2. Format it as ntfs
3. Unpack iso file in root of this partition
4. Reboot, enter grub and press "C"
5. Enter commands:

```
root=(hd0,3)
```

Where "0,3" is your disk number and partition number (for example, sda4 would be `hd0,4`, sdb2 would be `hd1,2`)

```
insmod ntfs
ntldr /bootmgr
boot
```

After `boot`, the Windows installer will start.

Comment: But i not remember, change partition to bootable or not